# WaterMarking on gif image

Tags: php, gif, watermark

So I am watermarking the png image on Gif image.here is my code :

```
<?php
// Load the stamp and the photo to apply the watermark to
$stamp = imagecreatefrompng('add_item.png');// watermark image
$im = imagecreatefromjpeg('gif_image.gif');// source image
$image_path = "/opt/lampp/htdocs/my/Harshal/watermarking/".time().".png";

$marge_right = 10;
$marge_bottom = 10;
$sx = imagesx($stamp);
$sy = imagesy($stamp);

// Copy the stamp image onto our photo using the margin offsets and the photo 
// width to calculate positioning of the stamp. 
imagecopy($im, $stamp, imagesx($im) - $sx - $marge_right, imagesy($im) - $sy - $marge_bottom, 0, 0, imagesx($stamp), imagesy($stamp));

// Output and free memory
//header('Content-type: image/png');
imagepng($im,$image_path);
imagedestroy($im);
?>
```

My code is working fine and its watermarking the png image on gif image but The problem is :
**There is white background coming just behind of the watermark png image and not the transparent as comes for other images.**

Can you guys tell me why only gif image have issues ?

See the generated image.
[image]

I know Gif is the combinations of many images but is there any solution that we can put the image with normal behavior.? 
I saw some Online watermarking tools also but they have also same issue.

Comment: If the color set as "transparent" in your PNG is not the same as your GIF, it will show opaque.

Comment: Here also a good example: [Link](http://phppot.com/php/php-watermark/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert the gif to a true color image. Try this:

```
<?php
// Load the stamp and the photo to apply the watermark to
$stamp = imagecreatefrompng('add_item.png');// watermark image
$im = imagecreatefromgif('gif_image.gif');// source image
$image_path = "/opt/lampp/htdocs/my/Harshal/watermarking/".time().".png";

$marge_right = 10;
$marge_bottom = 10;
$sx = imagesx($stamp);
$sy = imagesy($stamp);

// Convert gif to a true color image
$tmp = imagecreatetruecolor(imagesx($im), imagesy($im));
$bg = imagecolorallocate($tmp, 255, 255, 255);
imagefill($tmp, 0, 0, $bg);
imagecopy($tmp, $im, 0, 0, 0, 0, imagesx($im), imagesy($im));
$im = $tmp;

// Copy the stamp image onto our photo using the margin offsets and the photo 
// width to calculate positioning of the stamp. 
imagecopy($im, $stamp, imagesx($im) - $sx - $marge_right, imagesy($im) - $sy - $marge_bottom, 0, 0, imagesx($stamp), imagesy($stamp));

// Output and free memory
//header('Content-type: image/png');
imagepng($im,$image_path);
imagedestroy($im);
```